# Normal for scripts to be loaded after body tag?

Tags: javascript

Why are there WP scripts being loaded after the `<body>` tag? Is this the norm in WP? These scripts seem to be WordPress's own and not from the plugin/theme I am using. The image below is a screenshot of my console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happens when something is incorrectly outputting markup within the head tag that should be inside the body tag. The browser rendering engine moves the body tag before whatever markup is incorrectly inserted. It looks like your `#wrapper` div is the likely culprit here and is being output in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's normal. You will often find many inline script and imported scripts at different points within the body tag.